# Access violation using VBO with glew

Tags: opengl, vbo, glew

I'm trying to use VBO in my OpenGL project. I'm using glew library for extensions and glfw for windows handling.  When I try to create VBO application crashes and I get

> Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in symulator3C.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation

in function glGenBuffersARB. Here's my code:

```
GLuint vboId1=0; //this is global variable

void createVBO(){
normalsVBO = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*3*(SIZE_X-1)*SIZE_Y*2);
verticesVBO = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*3*(SIZE_X-1)*SIZE_Y*2);
if(normalsVBO==NULL) exit(-1);
if(verticesVBO==NULL) exit(-1);

glGenBuffersARB(1, &vboId1); //HERE IT CRASHES!

// bind VBO in order to use
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboId1);

...
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(float)*3*(SIZE_X-1)*SIZE_Y*2, verticesVBO, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);             // activate vertex coords array
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

}
```

I don't know what's wrong. Of course before calling this function I call glewInit() and result is success.
EDIT: I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: What does your debugger tell you about where the program stops?

Comment: as it is mentioned it stops at line glGenBuffersARB(1, &vboId1). or do you mean something else?

Comment: Does your OpenGL implementation actually support `ARB_vertex_buffer_object`?  You don't seem to be checking for that extension via `GLEW`.

Comment: Post a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your program fails at the first use of a VBO related function, it sounds like you either didn't initialize GLEW properly (by calling `glewInit` once the GL context is created and active) or your hardware just doesn't support VBOs.

Just check if your hardware supports GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object or if the OpenGL version is at least 1.5, in which case you can use the core versions of the VBO functions (without the ARB suffix, but you still need a properly initialized GLEW for these, of course):

```
printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
if(!strstr(glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS), "GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object"))
    //no VBO extension
```

And make sure you work with a recent graphics driver. If you work with the Windows default driver, it may only support OpenGL 1.1.

Comment: I probably don't need to tell you but for those following along at home `GLEW` has its own set of [extension and version checks](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html).

Comment: I've got newest version of glew. @Christian Rau when I call glGetString(GL_VERSION) it returns null. Strange thing is that I have working examples of VBO but when I checked version of openGL in gl.h file there was 1.1. Now I'm trying to find new version of GL.h maybe it will help

Comment: @pchot Don't look for a new version  of GL.h, there is none. Every function higher than 1.1 is only available through the function pointer functionality, similar to extensions, and managed for you by GLEW. The actual implementation of these functions is then provided by your graphics driver. But the good old GL.h is only version 1.1 (at least on windows) and you won't change that.

Comment: @Christian Rau Ok, problem was I had glewInit() after creation of GL context but also after I called glGenBuffersARB. Stupid mistake and so much time lost :/ Thanks for help.